# Не удаётся преобразовать string

Tags: c#, строки, int

Подскажите как такое возможно, почему 756 не удаётся преобразовать в int? При этом срабатывает не всегда.

[image: Скриншот кода и ошибки]
PS: Помогло следующее, спасибо Andrew за подсказку.

```
        static public int GetInt(string sString)
    {
        try
        {
            int iReturn = 0;
            sString = string.Join(string.Empty, Regex.Matches(sString, @"\d+").OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Value));
            int.TryParse(sString, out iReturn);
            return iReturn;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Original ERROR : " + ex.Message+" {|"+ sString + "|}", "err", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `int.Parse`, `int.TryParse` в помощь.

Comment: int.Parse, int.TryParse тоже не помогает

Comment: На мой взгляд, вам стоит опубликовать ответ отдельно (и принять его можно). Этот код решает проблему невидимых символов в начале, конце и между цифрами. Единственно, следует заменить `int.TryParse` на `int.Parse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что там могут быть любые другие лишние символы. **В том числе те, которые не отображаются визуально,** а не только пробелы.

Можешь при помощи Regex-а вытягивать исключительно цифры из строки, а потом уже tryParse использовать.

например даный регекс работает с интами и с числами с плавающей точкой:

```
"^-?\\d*(\\.\\d+)?$"
```

Comment: Ты прав, sString.Replace(" ", "")[0].ToString() показывает пустоту хотя визуально в нулевой позиции должна быть цифра. А также Length показывает большее значение чем видно цифр.

Comment: Здесь принято вместо коментария о правости достаточно поставить голос + отметить ответ как правильно. Спасибо :) Хорошего дня и удачный начинаний :)

Comment: Я бы поставил но пишет "Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга." а как набрать не знаю. И "отметить ответ как правильно" такой кнопки нет.

Comment: под голосом вверх или вниз - галочка "отметить ответ правильным"

Comment: Нашёл, отметил, спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: В топку эту регулярку. Из-за символов `^` и `$` она не сработает, если невидимые (и вообще нецифровые) символы будут в самом начале и конце. Также она не сработает, если такие символы будут между цифрами. Ну и к тому, же зачем плавающая точка, ведь в вопросе конкретно `int`.